# Cache friendly C code

Tags: c, caching

I want to calculate the cache miss rate per loop iteration of using this code-snippet:

```
int x[2][256];
int i;
int sum = 0;

for(i = 1;i < 256; i++) {
    sum += x[0][i] * x[1][i];
}
```

Assumptions:

1. Array x starts at 0x0
2. Cache is empty
3. Direct mapped cache with size 1024 byte and blocksize 32 byte

I would say we have a miss rate of one miss per loop iteration because we are also going through the colums of x. Is it right?

Next question: What is the miss rate if the cache size is 2048 byte?

Comment: This question is like asking "I have a car with 3.0 L engine. What is 0 to 60 time?".

Comment: Not to mention the `for ( i = =;...`

Comment: Sorry if its unclear, what additional information do you need? Its the cache analysis like in Bryants Computer system book chapter 6.